# SQL Update with Variable as Parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I am working on a stored procedure in MySQL to update a row in a SQL table.  What I have is a table where several of the columns are named incrementally.  EX: Page_1, Page_2, Page_3....etc.
The data stored in these locations is updated at different times and I  have another column to store the number of times the row has been updated.  The count variable gets incremented each time the procedure runs and that allows me to utilize it's value in keeping track of where the next update of the data should take place.

From my research I keep finding solutions utilizing "Dynamic SQL."  I do not understand how to utilize this to resolve my issue.

I want to pass a variable in to an update statement as the column name.

The code I currently have is as follows.

```
 SET COUNT = COUNT + 1; -- modify count from count column
 SET COLUMNLOCATIONVARIABLE = CONCAT('Page_' , COUNT); -- concatenate the count with the column "Prefix"

 UPDATE Table
 SET COLUMNLOCATIONVARIABLE = INPUTVARIABLE --Use the concatenated statement as the column name and update it with input data
 WHERE mainID = INPUTID;
```

If anyone could explain to me how to pass this variable in as a column name using Dynamic SQL or another solution utilizing non-dynamic SQL I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the way to use a database. Create a new table for your `Page_*` columns, linked to the main table by an identity, with a page number column. Then you can update and include as many pages as you need, addressed by the main identity and the page number.

Comment: Thank you very much for the ideas Mike.  I understand that this is not the correct way to utilize a database, but I still do not understand how splitting those columns would make it any easier to know where to update the new data to.